enableEdgeToEdge() doesn't work on ComposeView
I have a fragment and ComposeView inside of its view.
The fragment has a button that triggers the display of the bottom sheet.
binding.composeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(
                ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed
            )
            setContent {
                **enableEdgeToEdge()**
                if(bottomSheetOpen.collectAsState().value) {
                    MyBottomSheet(
                        onClickClose = { bottomSheetOpen.value= false },
                    )
                }
            }
        }

and my bottomsheet is showing over the system navigation bar.
so I put enableEdgeToEdge() inside of the setContent {}
But it is still having the same issue.
what am I missing?
article I have referred: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge

enableEdgeToEdge is a method you use in your activity, not in a fragment.
